# How can I achieve this custom UIViewController Transition from UICollectionViewController to UIViewController?

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller, navigation, transition

On `selection` of a `UICollectionViewCell` I'd like the selected item to **pop** out of the `UICollectionView` as part of the navigation to a new `UIViewController`. To clarify, I don't need it to be removed.

The tap and text animation is simple and unimportant for this question.

I created a gif to show what I'd like to do, I'm just not sure of the best approach, I'm hoping you can guide my effort. As for requirements, `iOS 8`, ideally using `AutoLayout`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check  [this exellent article](http://dativestudios.com/blog/2013/09/29/interactive-transitions/) out(look the demo first), you will get what you need. Let me know if this help.